# How to solve such question: Find an example of 2 by 2 matrices E and F such that EF = 0, although no entries of E or F are zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question asks to *find an example of 2 by 2 matrices E and F such that EF = 0, although no entries of E or F are zero.*

Seems the question is open-ended, there are quite a lot of answers to this question. What are the correct steps to solve such a question? Here is one of the solutions from my try-and-error process:

$$E = F = \left[
\begin{matrix}
  1&-1\\
  1&-1
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

Comment: The easiest way is the direct way. Write each matrix with four parameters, compute the product. This gives you four equations in eight variables. Then solve the system. Only solutions with all variables nonzero are valid. You can "classify" all solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Therefore my try-and-error approach is correct, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_3 \cr a_2 & a_4\end{pmatrix},\;
B=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_3 \cr b_2 & b_4\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $AB=0$ is equivalent to the equations
\begin{align*}
0 & = a_1b_1 + a_3b_2\\
0 & = a_1b_3 + a_3b_4\\
0 & = a_2b_1 + a_4b_2\\
0 & = a_2b_3 + a_4b_4
\end{align*}
Since all parameters are nonzero, we have the solution
\begin{align*}
b_2 & =-a_2b_1/a_4,\\
b_4 & = -a_2b_3/a_4,\\
a_3 & = a_1a_4/a_2.
\end{align*}
So a complete classification of all matrices $A$,$B$ with nonzero entries and $AB=0$ is given by
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_1a_4/a_2 \cr a_2 & a_4\end{pmatrix},\;
B=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_3 \cr -a_2b_1/a_4 & -a_2b_3/a_4\end{pmatrix}
$$
for nonzero $a_1,a_2,a_4,b_1, b_3$. Note that $\det(A)=\det(B)=0$ here, as it should be.

Comment: That's easier for me to understand, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

For $EF=0$, if one of $E$ or $F$ is invertible, the other must be zero. Hence the $E$ and $F$ that you are looking should be singular and every entry nonzero. This means they are rank-one matrices.

All rank-one matrices can be written in the form of $uv^T$ for some nonzero vectors $u$ and $v$. Since the question also requires $E$ and $F$ to be entrywise nonzero, we shall let $E=uv^T$ and $F=xy^T$, where $u,v,x$ and $y$ are entrywise nonzero vectors. Then $EF=(uv^T)(xy^T)=u(v^Tx)y^T$. It follows that $EF=0$ if and only if $v^Tx=0$.

In other words, all you need is to find two entrywise nonzero vectors $v$ and $x$ such that $v^Tx=0$, and they put $E=uv^T$ and $F=xy^T$ for any two entrywise nonzero vectors $u$ and $y$. The example that you have found amounts to the special case where $u=x=\pmatrix{1\\ 1}$ and $v^T=y^T=(1,-1)$.